# WindowsUWP not found in Mvvmcross namespace

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.windows

Hi Xamarin/MvvmCross devs,

I just tried to upgrade my v3.5.1 MvvmCross app to V4.+ but ran into an error. The app originally is a Windows Phone 8.1 application, I installed the latest MvvmCross and started using MvxWindowsPage for the xaml.cs partial class because MvxPhonePage was not in the assembly anymore.

I am now running into this error

```
The type or namespace name 'WindowsUWP' does not exist in the namespace 'MvvmCross' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

in the generate view.g file.

I'm using MvvmCross V4.4.0 at the moment. Am I missing something on my side?

I'm open to any suggestions. Thank you

**EDIT 1**

The references as added by Mvvmcross to the Windows phone 8.1 project is:

- MvvmCross.Core
- MvvmCross.Platform
- MvvmCross.Platform.WindowsCommon
- MvvmCross.WindowsCommon

Comment: What is the namespace for the MvxWindowsPage you are using?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'm using MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views as the namespace.

Comment: And is this still a Windows Phone 8.1 project?

Comment: I think you are forced to use MvvmCross 4.3.0 for that

Comment: @Cheesebaron Oooooooo :( I'll get back to you, I'm only jumping onto that project in a few hours. Thank you so much for your replies

Comment: @Cheesebaron didn't fix anything. Still getting issues regarding that namespace.

Comment: Strange, I am using it in a WP8.1 app and running 4.3.0. Are you sure you are not missing a package?

Comment: @Cheesebaron This is driving me crazy. Updated my answer with the references that were added by mvvmcross nuget installation